# Starting a PHP Session from HTML log in form

Tags: php, html, forms

what I want to do is start a php session for the username, right after the form so it brings up the username once the user has pressed submit. 
Here's the code for the form I have:

```
<form name="login" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="submit" name="login"  value="Login" />
</form>
```

What do I do after that? Thanks.

Comment: after that type in some php.

Comment: Have you initiated the session at the top of the page already?

Comment: No, I'm not entirely sure how to do that I'm still new to Sessions and still confused by half of it.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified way; put this on top of the page (above) the html code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login']) {

    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];

}
```

Now use that new `Session` variable where you need as the username.  If you close your browser.  It's no longer stored.  (Unless you set a `cookie`.)

Comment: Okay so say I put action="that code" near the submit button code and how do I make the login form disappear and bring up "You are logged in as: 'username'" after it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use jQuery/AJAX. That might do what you're after

Comment: One way (maybe not the greatest for the sake of code readability) would be to surround the `HMTL` code in a `php` if statement.  If `$_POST['login']` is set, don't show it.  Often times, in the top, I simply send the page somewhere else after the login is set -- the SESSION variable is still stored and you can use it on any page (assuming the other page has correct code to set it up).

Comment: Right, okay hopefully I can get this right thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: Sorry I had a typo.  It's `session_start` not `start_session`